# Changing CSS of Angular UI dropdown list doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/fQgJewkaa4b07uHaRzrb?p=preview) I have an Angular UI dropdown list with a class that attempts to change the color of the items in the list when the cursor is on the item (on hover)

I tried assigning a class to the `<li>` on hover and it doesn't work. Setting the class without on hover does work.

This is the attempt:

CSS

```
li.ddl-li {
  background-color:yellow;   /* works */
}

li.ddl-li:hover {
  background-color:orange;  /* doesn't work */
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
    <button id="btn-append-to-body" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
           uib-dropdown-toggle="">{{selection}} <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-click="selectItem($event)" uib-dropdown-menu="" 
            role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body">
       <li role="menuitem" class="ddl-li">
          <a href="#" data-value="1" >The first item</a>
        </li>
        <li role="menuitem" class="ddl-li">
          <a href="#" data-value="2">Another item</a>
        </li>
        <li role="menuitem" class="ddl-li">
          <a href="#" data-value="3">Yet another item</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the `background-color` of the `<a></a>` element inside your custom class. 
 
I've forked your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DzGSen4VQBgg9H9GOnTT?p=preview)

**CSS:**

```
li.ddl-li a {
  background-color: yellow;
}

li.ddl-li a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

**Option without add a custom class. 
You can override `.dropdown-menu` bootstrap class :**

```
ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  background-color: #eee;
}

ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

change to a element instead of li. a took cover all li elemt, so you hover a, not li

```
li.ddl-li a:hover {
      background-color:orange;
    }
```